# sentiment mining for tamil movie review

Tags: java

I am trying to read a tamil text file in java using netbeans. am getting output as simply blank small boxes.
My focus is i need to read the tamil text file and each sentence need to split as words. the code is given below kindly check and give me the suggestion how to get it.

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock;

class words {
    private static String[] words;
    private static String[] word;
    public boolean isTamil(String text){  
        boolean result = true;  
        UnicodeBlock tamilBlock = UnicodeBlock.forName("TAMIL");  
        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){  
            UnicodeBlock charBlock = UnicodeBlock.of(text.charAt(i));  
            if(!tamilBlock.equals(charBlock)){  
               result = false;  
            }  
        }  
        return result;  
    }  
    public static void split (String[] query, String[] words) throws IOException {
    String s = "This is a sample sentence.";
    String[] word = s.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // You may want to check for a non-word character before blindly
    // performing a replacement
    // It may also be necessary to adjust the character class
       word[i] = word[i].replaceAll("", "");
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic hereString fileName="W:/head.txt";
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("W:/first.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;

    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    // Print the content on the console
       split(word,words);
       System.out.println (strLine);
    }
    br.close();
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you encounter? What you have tried?

Comment: i tried to spilt the sentence into words and also to read the tamil text file. but it shows oly blank boxes and also it doesnt split the words.

Comment: Add the input and output here

Comment: Input: அஜீத், தமன்னா, விதார்த், நாசர், சந்தானம், பாலா, அதுல் குல்கர்னி, பிரதீப் ராவத், முனீஷ், சோஹைல் ஒளிப்பதிவு - வெற்றி எடிட்டர் - மு காசி விஸ்வநாதன் வசனம் - சிவா, பரதன் தயாரிப்பு - விஜயா புரொடக்ஷன்ஸ் எழுத்து, இயக்கம் - சிவா தமிழ் சினிமாவின் எவர்கிரீன் வெற்றி ஃபார்முலாவான அண்ணன் - தம்பி பாசம், காதலை கமகம பொங்கல் மசாலாவாகத் தந்திருக்கிறார் இயக்குநர் சிவா.

Comment: where do u define words?

Comment: output comes like this blank boxes [] [] [] [] []

Comment: in class words.   i am new to java

Answer (score 0):

This is because its a character encoding problem. Netbeans like IDE would be using the default OS encoding and hence it will print boxes or other funcky characters.

The possible solution is to set your Character encoding to **UTF-8**

> open the project pane if you don't see it already (Window > Projects)
>   Right-click on the name of your project in the tree-view click
>   properties make sure the menu item "sources" on the left is
>   highlighted you should see "Encoding:" and a select-box next to it.
>   click ok.

done.